# Jquery, animate current div width with + 10px

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, width

I am trying to make a div get 10 px bigger than the current width of the div.
So if I have multiple divs with different widths they dont all become 200 px,
but the 140px div becomes 150px and the 210px div become 220px.

```
            $(function() {

            var $menu = $('#ldd_menu');
            $menu.children('li').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var $span = $this.children('span');
                $span.data('width',$span.width());

                $this.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    $menu.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();
                    $span.stop().animate({'width':'200px'},300,function(){
                        $this.find('.ldd_submenu').slideDown(100);
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    $this.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true,true).hide();
                    $span.stop().animate({'width':$span.data('width')+'px'},300);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: what's the problemo ??

Comment: How I can do that, I am a beginner in jquery. Make the div 10px bigger than the current size. No matter how big it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting an absolute value, you can use an offset to the current width using `+=[amount]px` or `-=[amount]px`:

```
$span.stop().animate({ width: '+=10px' }, 300, function() {});
$span.stop().animate({ width: '-=10px' }, 300, function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use --

```
$span.stop().animate({'width':'+=10px',......});
```

> 10px bigger than the current size

`+=10px` is solution to that.

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7wFYj/)